# Excel: Replace certain part of string, leave the rest

Tags: excel

I have a 4,000+ row file that I want to sort by date.
The software I've exported the CSV from has the dates in this format:

```
Sun 06 Aug 2017 14:45 UTC
```

Excel doesn't seem to be able to work with this, so I'm trying to remove the day (Sun), the time and UTC.

I removed the day with this:

```
= RIGHT(B2, LEN(B2)-4)
```

and then used LEFT to take out the numbers and UTC.
However this only works because what I want to remove happens to be at the start and end of each cell - my question is how can I use a formula to remove the numbers, or a find and replace? I tried to find
`"**:**"`
 for the time and replace it with "" but this replaces the entire string.

Answer (score 0):

Think about your process as *extracting what you want*  instead of as *replacing what you don't want*

To convert to a date:

```
=--MID(A1,5,11)
```

or

```
=DATEVALUE(MID(A1,5,11))
```

You will see a number like `42953` which represents the date.  You can either just sort on that directly, or format the value as a date for appearance sake.

To convert to an Excel date/time:

```
=--MID(A1,5,17)
```

This will return a number like `42953.61458` which you can format as a date, time, or both and sort on it if you like.